# php_flag engine off subdirectories?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a dir where I put an htaccess file with the following rule in order to disable php execution

```
php_flag engine off
```

However, if I put a php file in a subdirectory and try to call it from the browser. The php file is successfully executed.

How can I apply the rule above to affect subdirectories as well ?

**NOTE: Subdirectories are created dynamically so I can't manually put an htaccess file on each of them**

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Debian Wheezy (oldstable) with PHP 5.4.34 and Apache 2.2.22.